# Algorithm to resize an image below a size in bytes depending on original image resolution

Tags: java, algorithm, image, formula, image-resizing

Is there a good algorithm to resize images below a file size (lets say 250kb) depending on the original image dimensions?

Currently in java i have:

```
public static byte[] resize(byte[] data, int desiredSize, String type) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage img = arrToBufferedImage(data);
        int factor = 10;
        double aspectRatio = (double) img.getWidth() / (double) img.getHeight();
        while (data.length / 1024 > desiredSize) {
            data = imgToBytes(resize(img, img.getWidth() - factor, (int) (img.getHeight() - (factor / aspectRatio))), type);
            img = arrToBufferedImage(data);
        }
        return data;
}
```

which just removes 10px from the width and some from the height to maintain aspect ratio.
The problem im having is when an image is already quite small (lets say 260 kb), scaling it by a factor of 10 px would decrease the file size by alot, ive seen it become 17 kb just by removing pixels with the factor 10.
So im looking for an algorithm that would use a lower factor for smaller image dimensions, and when having large image dimension, it would use a larger factor.
I have tried myself but im not good enough at maths to come up with such formula.

Comment: I don't think the huge decrease comes from the reduction in size. To me, it looks as if writing out the image omits some metadata or perhaps pallette information. You don't say what format your images are in or what dimensions they have. It also depends a lot on how good you can compress them, that is how much detail they have.

Comment: the format can be any, there is the type parameter for. the image the large decrease happened with was a png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scale down an image to 1MB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66311867/how-to-scale-down-an-image-to-1mb)