# How to scale down an image to 1MB?

Tags: image, image-processing

I am looking for a python based solution where I can scale down an image (img<=1MB) if it is bigger than 1MB or keep the original if it's already under 1MB.

e.g.

- img1; size = 1.2MB -> scale it down to 1MB
- img2; size = 0.9MB -> keep it as it is.
- img2; size = 1.0MB -> keep it as it is.

Till now I have come to this which scales down an image with a given percentage.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')
scale_percent = 0.4

new_width = int(img.shape[1]*scale_percent)
new_height = int(img.shape[0]*scale_percent)
dimension = (new_width, new_height)

resized = cv2.resize(img, dimension, interpolation = cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

print(resized.shape)
cv2.imwrite('img_resized.jpg', resized)
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to change the height and width to reduce the file size in bytes? People normally retain the same height and width but reduce the quality to make the byte-size smaller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general the size of an image is affected by:

- width `w` and height `h`;
- number of channels `n`;
- size of data type `t`;
- data compression.

If there is no compression (*e.g.*, in .bmp images) the size `S0` (in bytes) of the image is given by:

```
S0 = w * h * n * t
```

Considered that a scaling transform can only affect the variables `w` and `h`, the size `S1` of an image whose dimensions are scaled by a factor `s` is

```
S1 = (s*w) * (s*h) * n * t
```

Since `S1 = (s*s) * S0`, to constrain the size `S1` to be less or equal to 1 MB, `s` should be chosen so that `(s*s) * S0 <= 1`, hence `s <= sqrt(1/S0)`. In order not to upscale the images that already have a size smaller than 1MB, the formula should me modified as follows:

```
s = max{sqrt(1/S0), 1}
```

For compressed images the explicit determination of the size is more complicated, but the rule for the determination the scale factor `s` should be a good approximation.

Comment: Note that PNG generally **are** compressed and actually also filtered first to optimise compressibility.